# Making objects available application wide : Java EE

Tags: jakarta-ee

My use case is :

1. Some user makes a get request and creates an object which runs a command prompt.
2. another user want to kill the process created in step 1 by making another get request.

so I want to access the object created in 1st get request in the second get request,i.e.,I want to make the object available application wide.

In the Java SE I would make a list of objects in main method and pass it as a parameter to method which creates the new object.It will add the newly created object in the given list.another method,which has to kill the process,will pick the object from this list.but in EE I don't have a main method,so where to store objects that are available application wide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a singleton object with your syncronized list will work as intended

Comment: can you explain more.where to create this singleton object with list.There is no main method in EE,right?.Please explain,I am new to java EE

Comment: A singleton, as described in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern, is an object which can only have a maximum of 1 instances in the JVM at any given time. It's not a JavaEE concept, but a generic design pattern. So once you create it on your first request, it should be available everywhere in your application since you always reference the same object

Comment: I would really appreciate it if whoever downvoted the answer, posted an explanation as well. I'm very much interested in seeing what I might have mistaken and learning something new. Cherrs

Answer (score 3):

If you are absolutely certain about utilizing the global scope (having solved e.g. synchronization issues), then you can:

1. In web application context, use the `ServletContext` ([Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html)):

   - From JSP using the `application` implicit variable.
   - From servlet using `getServletConfig().getServletContext()`

   The `ServletContext` behaves like a map for your needs, with methods `setAttribute(String, Object)`, `getAttribute(String)` and `removeAttribute(String)`. You can put the list you were talking about for the Java SE case in there.
2. In EJB context:

   - Use the JNDI (kind of awkward and application server specific)
   - Wrap your list in a `@Singleton` session EJB (much better)
3. From either web or EJB, using CDI:

   - Wrap your list in an `@ApplicationScoped` bean (a singleton in CDI terms)